# Heroku and Ruby Sets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

So I'm building a Rails app and I was making use of the Set class that Ruby provides (docs here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html).

In my code I have:

```
require 'Set'
```

and everything runs well locally.

However, Heroku seems to stumble, giving the error:

```
LoadError (cannot load such file -- Set)
```

I have tried googling but the broadness of the word "Set" seems to contaminate my results. Is there any way to setup Heroku to allow me to use the Set datatype?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply do:

```
require 'set'
```

Libs shouldn't be capitalized.

Comment: Actually now it just returns false. What gives?

Comment: I got false from the Heroku console... However the actual Rails app on heroku is working now. Leads me to believe it was be required by default. Thanks!

Comment: Easily checked: Can you create a set? (Set.new)

Comment: What's the problem? `false` means that the file wasn't loaded because it had already been loaded before. So, it worked.

Comment: The problem in the end was the use of a capital S rather than a lower case s